# how to append value in td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting dynamic values in table using Datatables. I am getting my desired value in alert, but I want to show that value in table. for that purpose I used .append, .html but no luck. How can I show = my value in `<td>`. I also try to gave gave td an id e.g `<td id="files">`
here is my code:

```js
function format(d) {
  var str = d.files;
  var myarr = str.split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
    alert(myarr[i]);
    $("#files").append("<a href='/uploads/" + myarr[i] + "'>" + myarr[i] + "</a>");
  }
  
  // `d` is the original data object for the row
  return '<table id="ChildRows" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Contact Person:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.person + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Phone:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.phone + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Web:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.web + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Trade Type:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.ttype + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Files:</td>' + '<td id="files">'
  '</td>' +
  '</tr>' +
  '</table>';
}
```

I hope it will be a easy fix.any help will be highly appreciable

Comment: How are you calling `format()`? What are you expecting `this` to be a reference to?

Comment: $("#files").append("<a href='/uploads/" + myarr[i] + "'>" + myarr[i] + "</a>");

Comment: I want to append in td whose is files

Comment: Well the issue is that the `#files` element doesn't exist at the point you attempt to select it. You need to first add that HTML string to the DOM, then append to it. Alternatively, amend the logic which creates that HTML string to include the output of your `for` loop

Comment: I have no idea. any link ??

Comment: I added an answer below to show you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the `#files` element doesn't exist at the point you attempt to select it. You need to first add that HTML string to the DOM, then append to it.

Alternatively, you could amend the logic which creates that HTML string to include the output of your `for` loop, like this:

```js
function format(d) {
  var str = d.files;
  var filesHtml = str.split(",").map(function(file) {
    return '<a href="/uploads/' + file + '">' + file + '</a>';
  });
  
  return '<table id="ChildRows" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
    '<tr>' +
      '<td>Contact Person:</td>' +
      '<td>' + d.person + '</td>' +
    '</tr><tr>' +
      '<td>Phone:</td>' +
      '<td>' + d.phone + '</td>' +
    '</tr><tr>' +
      '<td>Web:</td>' +
      '<td>' + d.web + '</td>' +
    '</tr><tr>' +
      '<td>Trade Type:</td>' +
      '<td>' + d.ttype + '</td>' +
    '</tr><tr>' +
      '<td>Files:</td>' + 
      '<td id="files">' + filesHtml + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
  '</table>';
}

var html = format({ 
  person: 'John Smith',
  phone: '1234 567890',
  web: 'http://google.com',
  ttype: 'Foobar',
  files: 'a.jpg,b.jpg' 
});
$('div').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help